# two python lists dependency

Tags: python, list

Starting learning Python lists and stuck with the question

Simplifying I have a code:

```
A = []
B=[{'x':10},{'x':30}]
for elem in B:
       A.append(elem)     

for elem in B: ##changing B list
       elem['x']=elem['x']-1
print(A)
```

I've changed B list in the *for cycle* but last string output for A list is

`[{'x': 9}, {'x': 29}]`

So A list is affected too.

Could somebody explain why updating B list causes updating A list.

I expected A and B lists to be independent.
Probably the answer is in append method documentation or area of elem ​​visibility but cant find the exact answer

Comment: This is unrelated to lists, you are storing references to the same object. `elem` is not a copy of the `dict`s in your lists, it is a reference to them

Comment: http://pythontutor.com can help understanding this kind of thing.